# How to access local webpage from another host in the same network?

Tags: macos, network, webserver, rss

I'm trying to access RSS feeds hosted on my Mac from another computer in the same network.

The IP-address of the Mac is 192.168.228.84, the port the server uses is 8080.

I can access the page locally, but the Windows PC can't access it, instead it's saying ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

How would I fix this?

Comment: Most recent versions of both

Comment: "But my windows on the computer..."  Huh?  Are you running a (Microsoft) Windows VM on the same Mac or is this another Windows computer?  How are you accessing the feed *locally*?  What address are you using?

Comment: It's another, separate computer.  The url I'm accessing is `192.168.228.84:8080`, which works on the mac, but not on the windows

Comment: Are you running a firewall on *either* machine?  On the Mac, try `pfctl -d` to disable any firewall that's running. I don't have my Windows machine with me to tell you how to get to the Firewall settings, but see if you can be sure you're not blocking outgoing connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up determining that the problem was a firewall on the network, not on either device. Thank you for your help!